# convergence interval of an infinite series without the general term

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the convergence of an infinite series of which I do not have the nth term. Instead of applying the ratio test for the nth term, I divided the first two terms, then the next two and so on, until I get a convergence interval which looks about the same. Is this correct and does someone have a numerical scheme for finding convergence interval of an infinite series without the general term?

Comment: So, in other words, you applied the ratio test?

Comment: If you don't have a formula for the nth term, does that mean you know the first several terms only?  Strictly speaking the answer is no this is not valid.

Comment: Yes, but not to the general term since I don't know one. I applied ratio test for successive terms of the series. My hope is to eventually find an interval which looks about the same, so I do not need to perform further computation.

Comment: I can keep computing the next several terms of the series up to whatever number of terms I want, but I do not have a general formula.

Comment: I'm not especially trying to harass you, but I'm confused what the situation is where you can compute any specific term that you please but you do not know the nth term.  At any rate without more assumptions on the series you just can't say - what if the first ten thousand terms are perfectly nice and then things get disordered?

Comment: So you have a recurrence relation? That is, a formula that describes the nth term by using earlier terms. If so, what is your recurrence relation?

Comment: @JasonKnapp But what if I find the convergence intervals to be almost the same after let's say a thousand computations. Then, can I say that I have found the right convergence interval?

Comment: Speaking totally generally, no.  How about $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 10000$ and $a_n = n$ after that?  Sure that is a very contrived example, but unless you have more information to work with you can't say it is good enough.  Maybe you could provide more information about the series you are using?

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA No, it is not a recurrence relation. The terms of the series are obtained through a completely different procedure called "Method of Multiple Scales" which is a method to analytically approximate the solution of a non linear differential equation.